# multi table select after JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

```
TB1:
+---------------+---------------------+----------+
| uniqueid      | datetime_entry      | field_0  |
+---------------+---------------------+----------+
| 1517326336.62 | 2018-01-30 17:32:16 | somedata |
| 1517326336.62 | 2018-01-30 17:32:22 | somedata |
| 1517326477.64 | 2018-01-30 17:34:37 | somedata |
+---------------+---------------------+----------+

TB2:
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| uniqueid      | datetime_inti       | datetime_end        | id_emp |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 1517326336.62 | 2018-01-30 17:32:16 | 2018-01-30 17:32:16 | 1      |
| 1517326336.62 | 2018-01-30 17:32:22 | 2018-01-30 17:32:16 | 2      |
| 1517326477.64 | 2018-01-30 17:34:37 | 2018-01-30 17:32:16 | 3      |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+

TB3:
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
| uniqueid      | field_1  | field_2  | field_3  |
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1517326336.62 | somedata | somedata | somedata |
| 1517326336.62 | somedata | somedata | somedata |
| 1517326477.64 | somedata | somedata | somedata |
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+

TB4:
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Name_1    |
| 2  | F Name L. |
| 3  | F_name L. |
+----+-----------+
```

3 of them have the same `uniqueID` field.. so after some search, I figure out that I have to use JOIN to get the data I want from the 3 tables, now I need to add the 4th table, **But** the 4th table doesn't have `uniqueID` field.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    TB1  
    LEFT JOIN TB2 USING (uniqueid) 
    LEFT JOIN TB3 USING (uniqueid)
    )
WHERE 
    TB1.datetime_entry>='2018-01-30 00:00:00' 
    AND TB1.datetime_entry<='2018-01-30 00:59:59' 
    AND TB1.new_status <>  'status1' 
    AND TB1.new_status <>  'status2' 
ORDER BY TB1.datetime_entry;
```

there's a field in **TB2** called ***id_emp***, now I need to JOIN **TB4** which include ***name*** and ***address*** So, I need to return then name and address in the query result!!

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .

Comment: Your `TB2` has a field named `id_emp`. Do you mean it references to the `id` field of `TB4`?

Comment: @ShuwnYuanTee Yes

Comment: @scaisEdge, Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `JOIN` tables with `ON` expression. Assume `TB2` has a field named `id_emp`, this field is a `foreign key` to `id` field of `TB4`. Then join it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    TB1 LEFT JOIN TB2
        USING (uniqueid) 
    LEFT JOIN TB3
        USING (uniqueid)
    LEFT JOIN TB4
        ON TB2.id_emp = TB4.id    -- JOIN table with ON expression
WHERE
    TB1.datetime_entry >= '2018-01-30 00:00:00' 
    AND TB1.datetime_entry <= '2018-01-30 00:59:59' 
    AND TB1.new_status <> 'status1' 
    AND TB1.new_status <> 'status2' 
ORDER BY TB1.datetime_entry;
```

I see you are using `LEFT JOIN`, which means there might be record from `TB1`, but not necessary matching record exist in `TB2`, `TB3`, `TB4`. If records always exist in all tables, just use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. You can refer more explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I'm looking for, really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use an inner join on emp_id and id

```
  select TB1.uniqueid
    , TB1.datetime_entry
    , TB1field_0 
    , TB2.datetime_inti 
    , TB2.datetime_end  
    , TB2.id_emp 
    , Tb3.field_1
    , TB3.field_2
    , TB3.field_3
    , TB4.name
  FROM TB1 
  INNER JOIN TB2 ON TB1.uniqueid = TB2.uniqueid
  INNER JOIN TB3 ON TB1.uniqueid = TB3.uniqueid
  INNER JOIN TB4 ON TB2.id_emp = TB4.id
```